# PHP Proxy/TCP/IP Bridge

Tags: php, proxy, bridge

I'm looking for a php proxy but not a html one.

I mean, there is many php proxy which allow you to go to the proxy, enter an URL and see the content. This is not what I need.

What I'm looking for is something like if I call http://mydomain.com/mypage.php then this php page is simply calling http://mydomain2.com/myotherpage passing all the parameters, flows, etc. that the proxy will received, and returning what the mydomain2 will return.

So it might be like "a bridge", a "flow redirect" or something like that, but I don't really know how to call it.

I need to be able to call this URL from an application, sending a stream, and get it redirected.

Any idea?

Comment: It's a proxy script.  Plain and simple.  What you say you don't need and what you say you do need are identical...

Comment: there's no such thing as an 'html' proxy. You just want a proxy for arbitrary TCP connections. Look into SOX.

Comment: What I don't want is something like that: http://fastproxynetwork.com/
But what I want it to be able to do a URLConnection to an HTTP address, send a stream of data, and got it relayed to another server transparently.

I have a server waiting for connections on port 444 because 80 is blocked. And I have a GoDaddy hosting waiting for connections on port 80. I want to configure my application so it send the stream to GoDaddy on port 80 which redirect to my local server on port 444.